# Gettings XML information from an ip address

Tags: php, xml, ip-address

I have an IP adress and i need to get the XML data from it? I want do do this in with a PHP script. I've looked into `SimpleXMLElement` but im not getting it.

```
http://94.23.34.69:7240/

<ServerStats>
    <Name>IG_Battlegrounds</Name>
    <ModuleName>Native</ModuleName>  
    <MultiplayerVersionNo>1157</MultiplayerVersionNo>
    <ModuleVersionNo>0</ModuleVersionNo>
    <MapID>491</MapID>
    <MapName>Ruins</MapName>
    <MapTypeID>42</MapTypeID>
    <MapTypeName>Battle</MapTypeName>
    <NumberOfActivePlayers>26</NumberOfActivePlayers>
    <MaxNumberOfPlayers>50</MaxNumberOfPlayers>
    <HasPassword>No</HasPassword>
    <IsDedicated>Yes</IsDedicated>
    <HasSteamAntiCheat>No</HasSteamAntiCheat>
    <ModuleSetting0>20</ModuleSetting0>
    <ModuleSetting1>16</ModuleSetting1>
    <ModuleSetting2>0</ModuleSetting2>
    <ModuleSetting3>0</ModuleSetting3>
    <ModuleSetting4>1</ModuleSetting4>
    <ModuleSetting5>1</ModuleSetting5>
    <ModuleSetting6>0</ModuleSetting6>
    <ModuleSetting7>65</ModuleSetting7>
    <ModuleSetting8>0</ModuleSetting8>
    <ModuleSetting9>1</ModuleSetting9>
    <ModuleSetting10>2</ModuleSetting10>
    <ModuleSetting11>30</ModuleSetting11>
    <ModuleSetting12>330</ModuleSetting12>
    <ModuleSetting13>1</ModuleSetting13>
    <ModuleSetting14>5</ModuleSetting14>
    <ModuleSetting15>8</ModuleSetting15>
    <ModuleSetting16>100</ModuleSetting16>
    <ModuleSetting17>100</ModuleSetting17>
    <ModuleSetting18>100</ModuleSetting18>
</ServerStats>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just use [**`simplexml_load_file()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) to load external xml file in your code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://94.23.34.69:7240');
```

Comment: I used `$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://94.23.34.69:7240');` and then `print_r($xml);` and got like 5 warnings like this `Warning: simplexml_load_file(): http://94.23.34.69:7240:1: parser error : Document is empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\igwebsite\index.php on line 54` or `Warning: simplexml_load_file(): http://94.23.34.69:7240:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\igwebsite\index.php on line 54`

Comment: This means you are not downloading an xml from your IP

Comment: How should i do that?

Comment: Locate the xml address and chenge your actual address with the xml address

Comment: What's xml full address?

Comment: I don't know lol i only got this address :( How should it look like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49311/discussion-between-tom-and-fabio)

Comment: This is not a valid xml, it's just plain text

Answer (score 0):

PHP `file_get_contents` - https://www.php.net/file_get_contents

This gets a string containing the XML. Do what you wish with it.

Comment: I used code  `$xml = file_get_contents('http://94.23.34.69:7240'); ` and then `print_r($xml);` but im getting nothing.